# Как в HTML / CSS сделать emoji того же размера, что и текст?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

На моей веб-странице у меня есть всплывающее изображение в серии вложенных div.
В верхнем div у меня есть заголовок.
Пока загружается изображение с более высоким разрешением, в заголовке отображаются песочные часы эмодзи (⏳).
По завершении снимаю песочные часы. Когда песочные часы удаляются, div с текстом заголовка становится немного меньше по вертикали.
Как я могу сделать смайлик равным размеру текста, чтобы мой div не стал выше?

Вот фрагмент кода, который показывает div с голубым цветом фона и смайликами. Когда кнопка нажата, `innerHTML` заменяется текстом без эмодзи, и вы можете видеть, что вертикальный размер уменьшается.

```js
document.getElementById("button").onclick =
   () => {document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = "This is some text without emoji"};
```

```css
div.textWithEmoji {
    font-size : medium;
    background-color : cyan;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Emoji Size Test</title>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Emoji Size Test</h1>

<div class="textWithEmoji" id="div">
    This is some text with emoji ⏳
</div>

<br>

<button id="button" type="button">Remove Emoji</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Я не хочу устанавливать для высоты div определенное значение, поскольку размер шрифта - это переменная на моей странице.
Я попытался установить размер эмодзи на 75%, и это работает в Chrome и iOS, но нет гарантии, что это будет работать на каждой платформе.

Есть идеи, как я могу заставить это делать то, что я хочу?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [In HTML/CSS how can I make emoji the same size as the text?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67806940/7394871) от участника  [@Mike McCollister](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15551159/mike-mccollister).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/67806940/7394871

Answer (score 1):

Установите `line-height` для своего div:

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  $('.textWithEmoji').html("This is some text without emoji")
});
```

```css
div.textWithEmoji {
  font-size: medium;
  background-color: cyan;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Emoji Size Test</h1>

<div class="textWithEmoji" style="font-size:10px;">
  This is some text with emoji ⏳
</div>

<div class="textWithEmoji">
  This is some text with emoji ⏳
</div>

<div class="textWithEmoji" style="font-size:20px;">
  This is some text with emoji ⏳
</div>

<div class="textWithEmoji" style="font-size:30px;">
  This is some text with emoji ⏳
</div>



<button id="button" type="button">Remove Emoji</button>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67807146/7394871) от участника  [@иTemani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>